ClickListener not working in custom view class
I have a service class which controls device connection. When the device is connected to power, a custom view will be displayed. However, when I try to click on that view, the click is not working. Additionally, I have set animations, but they don't work either
Service
class Service : Service() {

    private var customLockScreenView: CustomLockScreenView? = null
    private var windowManager: WindowManager? = null

    private val powerConnectionReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            when (intent.action) {
                Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED -> powerWasConnected()
                Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED -> powerWasDisconnected()
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId", "InflateParams")
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        

        val filter = IntentFilter().apply {
            addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)
            addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)
        }
        registerReceiver(powerConnectionReceiver, filter)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(powerConnectionReceiver)
        powerWasDisconnected()
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    private fun powerWasConnected() {



        windowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager?

        if (customLockScreenView == null) {
            customLockScreenView = CustomLockScreenView(this)

            customLockScreenView!!.setClick(object : OnSingleClickListener {
                override fun onSingleClick() {
                    Log.d("Clicks Service", "Custom view clicked!")

                }
            })
            customLockScreenView!!.findViewById<LottieAnimationView>(R.id.animationView).setAnimation(R.raw.anim20)


            Log.d("TAG", "powerWasConnected: Power is connected")
            val layoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
                else
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                android.graphics.PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT,

                )
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            windowManager?.addView(customLockScreenView, layoutParams)
            

            Handler().postDelayed({

                customLockScreenView?.let {
                    windowManager?.removeView(it)
                    customLockScreenView = null 
                }

            }, 5000)

        }
    }

    private fun powerWasDisconnected() {
        Log.d("TAG", "powerWasDisconnected: Power is disconnected")
        clearFilter()
    }

    private fun clearFilter() {
        customLockScreenView?.let {
            windowManager?.removeView(it)
            customLockScreenView = null 
        }
    }

}

Custom View Class
class CustomLockScreenView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : RelativeLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    var clickListener: OnSingleClickListener? = null

    fun setClick(listener: OnSingleClickListener) {
        clickListener = listener
    }
    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_lock_screen, this, true)
        
        findViewById<LottieAnimationView>(R.id.animationView).setAnimation(R.raw.anim20)


        findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.main)?.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener?.onSingleClick()
        }

    }
}

Custom View Xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_toolbar"
    android:clickable="true">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/animationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/_55sdp"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/anim20"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_speed="1" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutBattery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_35sdp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPercentage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/regular"
            android:text="10%"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_30ssp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_battery" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_25sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_click"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>

Click Listener
abstract class SingleClickListener : View.OnClickListener {
    private var mLastClickTime: Long = 0

    abstract fun onSingleClick(view: View?)

    override fun onClick(view: View) {
        val currentTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
        if (currentTime - mLastClickTime > MIN_CLICK_INTERVAL) {
            mLastClickTime = currentTime
            onSingleClick(view)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val MIN_CLICK_INTERVAL: Long = 1000
    }
}

Click Interface
interface OnSingleClickListener {
    fun onSingleClick()
}


You are trying to set click listener on view with id R.id.main but in your CustomLockScreenView there is no view with this id. You can use the view2 which is root of your custom view, or you can just set the listener on the view itself.
You have to fix this:
findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.main)?.setOnClickListener {
   clickListener?.onSingleClick()
}

With solution using view2:
findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.view2)?.setOnClickListener {
   clickListener?.onSingleClick()
}

or with solution using the view itself:
this.setOnClickListener {
   clickListener?.onSingleClick()
}

